# Take FileItem.getInputStream as FileInputSTream

Tags: java

I am uploading a file with file Part and geting the `InputStream` on it as :

```
for (FileItem item : items) {


            if (!item.isFormField()) {

                content = item.getInputStream(); //require this as FileInputStream

                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

            }
```

which returns a `InputStream` object. Is there any way to get this as `FileInputStream` object?

Comment: can u show some more code?

Comment: please check edits